How to render HTML content with styles using CKEditor5 in Angular 13?
I have integrated CKEditor5 into my Angular 13 application and need to render HTML content with styles. However, my content is not displaying the styles as expected.
Here is a sample of my HTML content:
<style type="text/css">
.c10 {
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #32735f
}</style>
<p class="c9"><span><span class="c8">Hi&nbsp;</span></span><span><span
class="c10">{FirstName} {LastName}</span></span><span><span
class="c8">,</span></span></p>

When the HTML is rendered, the text with class c10 is not showing the green color style defined in the  tag.
What I have tried:
Ensured that the CKEditor5 configuration includes the necessary plugins for handling styles.
Verified that the CSS classes are correctly applied to the HTML elements.
Expected Behavior:
The text within the  tags should appear in the specified green color #32735f.
Actual Behavior:
The text does not display the specified green color.
Questions:
How can I ensure that the styles defined in the  tag are correctly applied to the HTML content rendered by CKEditor5?
Are there specific CKEditor5 configurations or Angular integrations that I need to adjust to support this?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I have enabled. But still styles were not refelcting
htmlSupport: {
            allow: [
            {
                name: /^.*$/,
                styles: true,
                attributes: true,
                classes: true
            },
            {
                name: 'div',
                attributes: true,
                classes: true,
                styles: true
            },
            {
                name: 'p',
                attributes: true,
                classes: true,
                styles: true
            },
            {
                name: 'span',
                attributes: true,
                classes: true,
                styles: true
            }
            ]
        }

